# Internet host is not accessible with VPN connected

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, vpn, connection

I've connected to my work VPN via KerioControl VPN Client. Everything was OK until today I've experienced connectivity issue with internet host:

```
ping api.nuget.org

Pinging cs9.wpc.v0cdn.net [72.21.81.200] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 72.21.81.200:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

If I'm turning VPN connection off, it fixes:

```
ping api.nuget.org

Pinging cs9.wpc.v0cdn.net [93.184.221.200] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 93.184.221.200: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=57
Reply from 93.184.221.200: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=57
Reply from 93.184.221.200: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=57
Reply from 93.184.221.200: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for 93.184.221.200:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 50ms, Maximum = 51ms, Average = 50ms
```

Note, that resolved IP is different. Now I'm confused about what the whole VPN thing is. Does it act as an intermediary between me and the Internet? How to diagnose the problem?

Worth to note, it's the new laptop and it can be the source of the problem. Before I had no such issues.

Comment: Remove the Checkbox "Use remote gateway as default" in your vpn connection (TCP/IP > Advanced).

Comment: I have no checkbox: https://snag.gy/NaJRBZ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Does it act as an intermediary between me and the Internet?

In a way yes, but the correct description is a encrypted tunnel, the VPN Client will encrypt it and the endpoint your connecting to will decrypt it again.

I'm not sure how to resolve this but it seems the VPN is up, as the DNS resolves to a different IP indicating it was resolved from the VPN site. I understand Nuget as being package manager repository for .net, this domain could well resolve differently either due to caching servers or just different path of DNS resolution.
Also when you are pinging this domain you will be pinging from behind their firewall when VPN is up. This maybe denied by the firewall rules in place at the site.

Are you the administrator of this KerioControl server ?

Comment: Yes, that is different dns resolving. I'm not admin. Not only pinging not works, but an http request is timed out for that exact host